# Visual Studio 17 vs Code::Blocks 17

Tags: c++

Muy buenas a tod@s :).

Tengo el siguiente código para comprobar si dos objetos de una lista de punteros a una clase `Objeto` están en la misma posición (x, y) y si están, borrar uno de ellos. Funciona perfectamente en Code::Blocks 17 pero en Visual Studio 17 lanza una excepción en la línea marcada con *'EXCEPCIÓN'* con el mensaje:

> 'list iterator not incrementable'

y no entiendo por qué. Me "obligan" a hacerlo en Visual Studio por eso tengo que arreglarlo. Como siempre si alguien me puede echar un cable se lo agradeceré enormemente :).

```
std::list<Objeto*> objetos_;

for (auto Obj = objetos_.begin(); Obj != objetos_.end(); Obj++)
    {
        for (auto Obj2 = Obj; Obj2 != objetos_.end(); Obj2++) ---> EXCEPCIÓN
        {
             if ((*Obj)->Get_X() == (*Obj2)->Get_X() && (*Obj)->Get_Y() == (*Obj2)->Get_Y())
             {
                 if ((*Obj)->Get_Nombre() != "USUARIO")
                 {
                      delete(*Obj);
                      Obj = objetos_.erase(Obj);
                 }
                 if ((*Obj2)->Get_Nombre() != "USUARIO")
                 {
                      delete(*Obj2);
                      Obj2 = objetos_.erase(Obj2);
                 }
             }
         }
     }
```

Comment: Y `objetos`... ¿qué tipo de objeto es?

Comment: @eferion es una lista de punteros de una clase llamada 'objeto' (soy muy poco original, lo se ;)) que es una clase abstracta.

Comment: perdón por no haberlo especificado.

Comment: "*una lista de punteros*"... `std::vector`? `std::list`? `std::set`?

Comment: Es un detalle importante que sería interesante que indicases en la pregunta... cada contenedor tiene un comportamiento diferente... si no solo tendríamos un contenedor en vez de media docena...

Comment: @ std::list<Objeto*> objetos_ es la declaración y mis disculpas de nuevo.

Comment: Eso ponlo en la pregunta, por favor... si alguien tiene que leerse los comentarios para entender la pregunta vas a perder muchas respuestas

Comment: @eferion muy cierto. Acabo de modificarlo.

Comment: Tiene toda la pinta que has incrementado el iterador que apunta a un elemento borrado.

Comment: @Paula_plus_plus si, eso parece. Lo que no entiendo es por qué en Code::Blocks no 'casca' ;).

Comment: @Battyhal porque el comportamiento indefinido puede provocar fallos, puede no provocarlos o puede [invocar demonios que saldrían disparados de tus fosas nasales](https://accu.org/index.php/journals/1857).

Comment: @Paula_plus_plus pero si el comportamiento indefinido puede o no provocar fallos o invocar las criaturas del Averno, ¿no es un poco raro que siempre se haya comportado del mismo modo, en este caso -aparentemente- de forma correcta?.

Comment: @Battyhal dije lo del comportamiento indefinido porque creía que estabas incrementando un iterador borrado, pero no es tu caso: descubrí que incrementas `end` lo cuál no es comportamiento indefinido si no comportamiento dependiente de implementación.

Comment: @Paula_plus_plus Aclarado entonces :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tiene toda la pinta que has incrementado el iterador `end`.

La función `list::erase` borra un elemento de la lista y devuelve el elemento a continuación del borrado, pudiendo ser este elemento el final de la lista (`end`) y siendo el final de la lista un elemento no incrementable (de ahí la excepción).

Deberías cambiar tus bucles para tener en cuenta esta particularidad:

```
for (auto Obj = objetos_.begin(); Obj != objetos_.end(); /*Obj++*/)
//                             No incrementamos aqui --> ~~~~~~~~~
{
    for (auto Obj2 = Obj; Obj2 != objetos_.end(); /*Obj2++*/)
    //                 No inctrementamos aqui --> ~~~~~~~~~~
    {
         if ((*Obj)->Get_X() == (*Obj2)->Get_X() && (*Obj)->Get_Y() == (*Obj2)->Get_Y())
         {
             if ((*Obj)->Get_Nombre() != "USUARIO")
             {
                  delete(*Obj);
                  Obj = objetos_.erase(Obj);
             }
             else
             {
                 ++Obj; // Incrementamos aqui
             }
             if ((*Obj2)->Get_Nombre() != "USUARIO")
             {
                  delete(*Obj2);
                  Obj2 = objetos_.erase(Obj2);
             }
             else
             {
                 ++Obj2; // Incrementamos aqui
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

Pero de todas maneras, este código además de ser incómodo de leer, está lejos del estilo de C++ moderno... y ni siquiera estoy segura de que funcione pues usas dos iteradores diferentes para recorrer una misma colección. Te aconsejo cambiar el código para usar la librería [`<algorithm>`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove):

```
auto borrar = std::remove_if(objetos_.begin(), objetos_.end(),
              [](Objeto* o)
              {
                  return o->Get_Nombre() == "USUARIO";
              });
```

La función [`std::remove_if`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove), mueve al final del contenedor los elementos que no cumplen con la condición y devuelve un iterador al primer elemento que no la cumplió, así que ahora se pueden borrar los punteros y eliminarlos de la lista:

```
std::for_each(borrar, objetos_.end(), [](Objeto* o) { delete o; });
objetos_.erase(borrar, objetos_.end());
```

Comment: Cierto... pasé por alto esta posibilidad

Answer (score 1):

Este algoritmo hace aguas... y el error no te está dando en visual studio sino que es dependiente del compilador... o mejor dicho, de la implementación de la librería estándar:

```
for (auto Obj2 = Obj; Obj2 != objetos_.end(); Obj2++)
```

Para empezar, en cada primera iteracción del segundo `for`, `Obj` y `Obj2` (yo los llamaría `It1` e `It2` ya que son iteradores, no objetos), apuntan al mismo elemento... luego en esta primera iteración se accede al `if` sí o sí.

En este contexto... ¿Qué sucede si el primer elemento es uno de los que hay que eliminar?

```
if ((*Obj)->Get_Nombre() != "USUARIO")
{
  delete(*Obj);
  Obj = objetos_.erase(Obj);
}
if ((*Obj2)->Get_Nombre() != "USUARIO")
{
  delete(*Obj2);
  Obj2 = objetos_.erase(Obj2);
}
```

Pasa que o bien se hace `erase` de `Obj` o bien de `Obj2`... pero ojo, que ambos iteradores son el mismo... si haces `erase` de `Obj` entonces `Obj2` se convertirá en un iterador no válido ya que el elemento al que apuntaba ya no se encuentra en la lista y lo mismo le pasará a `Obj` si se hace `erase` de `Obj2`:

```
// caso1:
Obj = objetos_.erase(Obj); // Obj2 ya no es valido

// caso2:
Obj2 = objetos_.erase(Obj2); // Obj ya no es valido
```

De hecho, podemos leer en la [documentación](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/erase) de la función lo siguiente:

> References and iterators to the erased elements are invalidated. Other references and iterators are not affected.

Es decir:

> Las referencias e iteradores al elemento a eliminar dejarán de ser válidos. El resto de iteradores y referencias no se ven afectados.

El caso es que el catálogo de problemas que podría llegar a darte es bastante extenso... si no te falla el iterador podrías incluso tener un error por doble borrado:

- En la iteración X se borra `Obj2`, con lo que `Obj` deja de ser válido
- En la siguiente iteración se borra `Obj`... que apunta a un elemento ya borrado... premio!!!

El problema se puede reproducir de otras tantas formas... pero el resumen es que si `Obj==Obj2` y haces un `erase`, uno de los dos iteradores va a dejar de ser un iterador válido y el algoritmo se te va a caer por algún lado.

Una posible solución:

```
for (auto Obj2 = std::next(Obj,1); Obj2 != objetos_.end(); Obj2++)
```

Así, `Obj2` empezará apuntando a la siguiente posición respecto a `Obj`.

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias por responder Paula_plus_plus y Eferion :).

Con respecto a :

> este código además de ser incómodo de leer, está lejos del estilo de C++ moderno

seguro que sí pero es la forma que conocía y no se me ocurría otra. Estoy empezando ahora con las lambdas. Gracias por la sugerencia y cambiaré el código por supuesto ;).

Y sobre :

> y ni siquiera estoy segura de que funcione pues usas dos iteradores diferentes para recorrer una misma colección.

te aseguro que funciona (lo puedes descargar aquí : https://github.com/battyhal/Bomberman.git)... en Code::Blocks y Zinjai que eran los que usaba, pero no en Visual Studio 17. Supongo que el compilador es más 'quisquilloso' en este último ;).